# NodeJS (Windows) - SyntaxError: missing X

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express

Unless there's something I don't understand, this seems to say ")" is missing and it point to ")".

```
});
 ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

This is generated from Guru99's Express.js tutorial file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.route('/Node',get(function(req,res)
{
    res.send("Tutorial on Node");
});
post(function(req,res)
{
    res.send("Tutorial on Angular");
});
put(function(req,res)
{
    res.send('Welcome to Guru99 Tutorials');
}));
```

The code looks ok to me.

Edit:

The resulting webpage says: Cannot get Node

Comment: Did you mean `app.route().get().post().put()`?  Because `post` and `put` aren't defined in your example.  In fact your example won't run.  Please provide an [mre].

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/node-js-express.html
I'm literally just following this guy's steps. Trying to accustom myself to js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong,
Please refer the [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for more info:

> ```
> app.route('/book')
>   .get(function (req, res) {
>     res.send('Get a random book')
>   })
>   .post(function (req, res) {
>     res.send('Add a book')
>   })
>   .put(function (req, res) {
>     res.send('Update the book')
>   })
> ```

So, in your case it will be:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.route('/Node')
.get(function (req, res) {
  res.send("Tutorial on Node");
})
.post(function (req, res) {
  res.send("Tutorial on Angular");
})
.put(function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to Guru99 Tutorials');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfect answer. Sorry for your time.